# Stop div table-cell from resizing in the center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a inline-table on a DIV which I have made resizable.

Basically, it allows someone to resize the table-cell's using jQuery.

If you exapand the inline-table and then resize the table-cell, how can I prevent the .spacer table-cell from expanding and shrinking in the centre? I would like the left position of the table-cell to remain on the left and only allow the right size to be expanding or shrunk?

I hope that makes sense! jsfiddle example here (please expand the outer div first and then resize the inner spacer div): http://jsfiddle.net/GT5Pc/

CSS:

```
    .draggableElementContainer {
    width:300px;
    border:#000 dashed 1px;
    display:inline-table;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
label {
        width: fit-content;
        max-width: fit-content;
        min-width: fit-content;
}
    .spacer {
        border: #000 dashed 1px;
        display: table-cell;
        white-space: nowrap;
       text-align: left;
       width: 100%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="draggableElementContainer">
    <label>Test</label>
    <div class="spacer">
       </div>
    <input type="input" id="test" />

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("div").resizable();
```

Comment: I think that while it's set as `display:table-cell;` it will have this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Add fixed `table-layout` to your `.draggableElementContainer` selector:

```css
.draggableElementContainer {
    ...
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GT5Pc/1/).

Comment: Yes that is basically what i'm after thank you but it seems to have stopped me being able to resize the DIV which the input box is inside?

Comment: @realtek that's because your table only has 1 table cell: the inner `div` element. You'll need to set your other elements to display as `table-cell` as well.